# How to create AJAX response into sessions in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I want to create my AJAX response into sessions in PHP. Here is my code, when I click this button:

```
<input type="button" id="callfunction" value="submit">
```

I am calling this jQuery:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#callfunction").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
        url:"ajax.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:"first_variable="+first_variable+"&second_variable="+second_variable,
        success:function(resp)
        {
            // can I create my resp into session here....?
        }

      });
    });
});
```

In ajax.php page I have some this values `$first_variable` and `$second_variable`:

```
ajax.php
$first_variable = $_POST['first_variable'];
$second_variable = $_POST['second_variable'];
echo $first_variable;
echo $second_variable;
```

Now in alert resp I vl get an alert message of **first_variable and second_variable**

Now my question I want to convert this two variables into session so that I can use this in that page with out passing it as hidden variables, is there any way we can convert it to sessions in the response function or I am going some where wrong?

Comment: Do you want send back to you main page a PHP $_SESSION ?

Comment: yes when i alert the resp it normally alerts the response in the same .php page i want to assign that response to my php variable which was created in sessions in ajax.php file how to achieve this i am not getting...plz help @guilherme Ferreira

Comment: your session is already created in ajax.php in my answer and you can read the session value. please check my answer.

Comment: Okey, So you have to set the $_SESSION variable with you $_POST (from the main page) and then send back with: `echo json_encode($yourArrayBack);`

Answer (score 2):

In **ajax.php** you have to initialize `session_start();` if you do not initialize your session will not work. Read on php.net [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

```
session_start();

$first_variable = $_POST['first_variable'];
$second_variable = $_POST['second_variable'];


$_SESSION['first_variable'] = $first_variable;
$_SESSION['second_variable'] = $second_variable;
```

Comment: Use json respose for this

Comment: you can get the session value by calling `$_SESSION['first_variable']` on every php page, **Note:** if you are unable to get the value try adding `session_start();` on the top of the .php page or it is better to create a config where you create session and database configuration.

Comment: i can create it the session variable there in my ajax.php here my question is in my resp page i want to assign it to my php variable for example <? php $resp_variable = session assigned in my ajax.php page ?> how to do it ....?

Answer (score 0):

Create session in ajax.php itself

**ajax.php**

```
    $first_variable = $_POST['first_variable'];
    $second_variable = $_POST['second_variable'];
    echo $first_variable;
    echo $second_variable;    
    $_SESSION["first_var"] = $first_variable;
    $_SESSION["sec_var"] = $second_variable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating session after getting response doesn't make any sense, 
So create the sessions before generating the response,

In ajax.php

```
<?php

start_session();  // Since we are using sessions;

$first_variable = $_POST['first_variable'];
$second_variable = $_POST['second_variable'];

$_SESSION[first_variable] = $first_variable;
$_SESSION[second_variable] = $second_variable;


echo $first_variable;
echo $second_variable;

?>
```